# angular 2/4 support in pdfreactor

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf-reactor

I tried to convert angular 4 view using PDfReactor. Only a page with "Loading..." was converted but not the actual views. I have read that in PDFreactor 8.2.8867 AngularJs can be used without workarounds. But I could not find documentation/examples which demonstrate the use of AngularJs. Is it possible to convert Angular 4 views using Pdfreactor?

Comment: can you make a plunkr or something so we can see the code to help

Comment: Well I have very simple angular 4 app.  When I tested with the server side rendered document (using Angular Universal) as an input document, it generated the pdf with actual view content. But with client side rendered document, the generated pdf only had 'Loading...' as a content. So I was just wondering if pdfreactor supports client side rendered document as an input document or not.

Comment: Loading... is typically the "error" you get when your app doesn't compile for some reasons. Look at your index.html files in your root directory, it is being displayed instead of over-written because of some error.

Comment: In the browser I can load the view and I don't see errors in the developers tools or in the ng serve log. I guess client side rendering is not yet supported by pdfreactor.

Comment: `In the browser I can load the view` what does that mean? normally the Loading... is often a bad export or import and won't allow you to really do anything

Comment: I mean in the browser, first the 'Loading...' is displayed and when angular parses the child components of ` <app-root>Loading...</app-root>`, 'Loading...' is then replaced by the child components view (html). So what I am trying to say is that pdfReactor does not seem to wait until angular parses all the child component's, so it only get 'Loading...' as the content of the input document,  cause that's the only thing rendered by the time pdfReactor take the input doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 4 is not yet supported, first tests indicate that it doesn't work in the current version of PDFreactor. Of course, we will try to support it in the future. AngularJS 2 should work with PDFreactor.

Comment: Okay. It would be really great if Angular 4 is supported without the use of Angular Universal (server side rendering). Thanks all for the response.